# What does “…because they had made up their minds, not to die,…” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can someone help me understand the meaning of this sentence?

> "I have seen Kru-men and others die in spite of every effort that was made to save them, simply because they had made up their minds, not (as we thought at the time) to die, but that being in the clutch of malignant demons they were bound to die."

To me the confusing part is "…, simply because they had made up their minds, not (as we thought at the time) to die…,"

Comment: Yuck.  Your confusion is understandable.  This is not a well constructed sentence IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You can break it down.

1)They died.

2)It wasn't because they had made up their minds to die.

3)It was because (being in the clutch of the demons) they had made up their minds that they were bound to die.

It basically means they died because they didn't see any way out.

Comment: I’d thought it was that the Kru-men assumed they were bound to die. That’s what they made up their minds about. But, agreed, it’s a bit of a long sentence and could have been better communicated.

Comment: @Pam. You are right. Sorry. I've edited answer. I think the last comma doesn't help matters, because it makes 'not to die' look as if it were in parenthesis.

Comment: I would still shift this slightly: "They had made up their minds, that being in the clutch of demons, they were bound to die"..  They had the conviction that [>they were possessed , and  therefore bound to die<].  Not that  the possession had  given them their conviction.